# number of distinct solution of Integral equation

Tags: integration

> Total number of distinct $0\leq x\leq 1$ for which $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^2}{1+t^4}dt = 2x-1$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $\displaystyle \underbrace{\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^2}{1+t^4}dt}_{\geq 0} = 2x-1\;,$ Where $0\leq x\leq 1$

So we get $\displaystyle x\geq \frac{1}{2}\;\;\;,$ Now  $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\left\{\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^2}{1+t^4}dt\right\} =\frac{d}{dx}(2x-1)$

So $$\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}=2\Rightarrow \underbrace{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}}_{\geq 2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

So no real values of $x$

Is my solution is Right, If not then how can i solve it some short way, Thanks

Comment: It looks just fine. You could also show directly $$x^2+\frac1{x^2}=\frac12\iff \left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+\frac32=0$$which cannot be solved in the reals as it is the sum of two non-zero positive numbers

Comment: Can we write is as $\displaystyle f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}dt-(2x-1)\;,$ Then $\displaystyle f'(x) = \underbrace{\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}}_{\leq \frac{1}{2}}-2<0$. So function is strictly decreasing function. So $f(x)=0$ has $1$ real roots.

Comment: Are you meaning that if $f(x)=g(x)$ then  $f'(x)=g'(x)$ ?

Comment: No I am just differentiating both side.

Comment: @juantheron - But you cannot do that. Your problem is an *equation* which is satisfied by *some* (possibly zero) values of $x$, it is not equality of two functions on the interval $0\leq x\leq 1$. This is not an uncommon error... However,  the approach in your previous comment is correct: on the interval $[0,1]$ the function $f$ has strictly negative first derivative, $f(0)=1$, and $f(1)=-0.756252...$: $f$ has precisely one zero in the open interval $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ x\mapsto \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} $$
is increasing on $[0,1]$, hence $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^2}{1+t^4}\,dt $ is non-negative and convex on $[0,1]$ and $f'(x)\leq f'(1)=\frac{1}{2}$ holds. It follows that $g(x)=f(x)-2x+1$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$. Since $g(0)=1>0$ and
$$ g(1) = \frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\log(1+\sqrt{2})}{2\sqrt{2}}-1 <0$$
it follows that $g(x)=0$ has only one solution in $[0,1]$.

Comment: +1. So, the **Bisection Method** is a useful tool $=>\ \approx 0.5231290362$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to find out the only solution whose existence has been given by Jack.

Integrating $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^2}{1+t^4}dt=\frac{1}{4\sqrt 2}\left(\log \left(\frac{x^2-\sqrt 2 x+1}{x^2+\sqrt 2 x+1}\right)+2\arctan(1+\sqrt2)-2\arctan(1-\sqrt2)\right) $$
Now graphing $f(x)=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^2}{1+t^4}dt$ without the denominator $4\sqrt2$ and $g(x)=4\sqrt2(2x-1)$ we get

[image]

In which the  only point of intersection is approximately $(x,y)=(0.523,0.262)$ hence $$\color{red}{x\approx 0.523}$$

Answer (score 1):

Trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599061/if-int-0x-fract2t4-1dt-2x-1-then-x/4599214#4599214) a simple estimate of the solution is
$$x=\frac 12+\frac{17}{120 \sqrt{2}}\left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}\right) +\log \left(\frac{33-20 \sqrt{2}}{17} \right)\right)\sim 0.523003$$